# VBscript for packing files

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, package, rename

I am very rusty in VB since it has been two years I have used it.  I will soon be diving back into it because I have more of a reason now to use it than ever.  Right now I am trying to create a VB script that will help me modify some files.  I currently need a way to take a folder and package them a certain way.  What I am trying to do is this:

- Take a folder with client name
- Create a zip file with said client name
- Add a certain file to it first which will not change (ship.xml)
- Take contents of client folder and add to zip folder.
- Rename .zip to .tar format

Also if you know any good site tutorials on VB please let me know.  I am using Visual Basic 2010 ultimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know exactly what you mean with clientname (computername ?), but this should get you started, you can add the rest yourself otherwise you'll stay rusty 8>)

```
zip = "c:\myzip.zip"
source = "G:\script\zip"

set fso = createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set shell = createObject("shell.application")
'make empty zip
set file = fso.CreateTextFile(zip, True)
file.write("PK" & chr(5) & chr(6) & string(18,chr(0)))
file.close

set objFolder = shell.NameSpace(source)
set oZip = shell.NameSpace(zip)
if not oZip is nothing then
  'add files to zip
  oZip.CopyHere objFolder
  wait_until_zipped(zip)
  oZip.CopyHere "c:\ship.xml"
  wait_until_zipped(zip)
  'rename the zip to tar
  fso.MoveFile zip, "c:\myzip.tar"
end if

'cleanup
set oZip = Nothing
set shell = Nothing
set fso = Nothing


function wait_until_zipped(zip)
  set handle = fso.getFile(zip)
  do
    wscript.sleep 500
    max = handle.size
  loop while handle.size > max
end function
```